# Scrapy printing last output three times instead of three of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script using scrapy to parse some content from a website. To access the relevant part of data from that site I need to use some ids within payload.

I'm trying with this three ids within payload one after another, as in `24842`,`19902` and `20154`. However, I'm trying to check whether the payload is update according to the ids I've used but I noticed that the payload is taking the last id, as in `20154` three times.

To be clearer I wanted to get output like:

```
{'language': 'en', 'region': 'ww', 'networks': 'Internet', '$top': '20', 'productNodePath': '/24842/'}
{'language': 'en', 'region': 'ww', 'networks': 'Internet', '$top': '20', 'productNodePath': '/19902/'}
{'language': 'en', 'region': 'ww', 'networks': 'Internet', '$top': '20', 'productNodePath': '/20154/'}
```

What I'm getting instead are:

```
{'language': 'en', 'region': 'ww', 'networks': 'Internet', '$top': '20', 'productNodePath': '/20154/'}
{'language': 'en', 'region': 'ww', 'networks': 'Internet', '$top': '20', 'productNodePath': '/20154/'}
{'language': 'en', 'region': 'ww', 'networks': 'Internet', '$top': '20', 'productNodePath': '/20154/'}
```

I've tried with:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class SiemensSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'siemens'

    start_link = "https://support.industry.siemens.com/webbackend/api/ProductSupport/ProductSearch?"

    payload = {
        'language': 'en',
        'region': 'ww',
        'networks': 'Internet',
        '$top': '20'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for item_id in ['24842','19902','20154']:
            self.payload['productNodePath'] = f"/{item_id}/" #should be updated here
            first_req = f'{self.start_link}{urlencode(self.payload)}'
            yield scrapy.Request(first_req,callback=self.parse)
        
    def parse(self,response):
        print(self.payload)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36',
        'LOG_LEVEL':'ERROR'
    })
    c.crawl(SiemensSpider)
    c.start()
```

***How can I achieve the first output?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `deepcopy` in this case combined with `meta` data in the request.

You are taking a property of the spider and just overwriting one of the values therefore you get the repeated data as mentioned in your problem.

Working example:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from copy import deepcopy


class SiemensSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'siemens'

    start_link = "https://support.industry.siemens.com/webbackend/api/ProductSupport/ProductSearch?"

    payload = {
        'language': 'en',
        'region': 'ww',
        'networks': 'Internet',
        '$top': '20'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for item_id in ['24842', '19902', '20154']:
            data = deepcopy(self.payload)
            data['productNodePath'] = f"/{item_id}/"  # should be updated here
            first_req = f'{self.start_link}{urlencode(data)}'
            yield scrapy.Request(first_req, callback=self.parse, meta={'payload': data})

    def parse(self, response):
        payload = response.meta.get('payload')
        print(payload)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36',
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'ERROR'
    })
    c.crawl(SiemensSpider)
    c.start()
```